# SQL length, left, right on new column

Tags: sql

Hello below is the code (new to SQL) . i need to trim 'Key_2 and create the new Column called Project_Code. how do i use len and left on this new Column "Project_Code". it looks like the code will work only on the original column "Key_2"

```
 select 
    KEY_1,
    KEY_2,
    Replace (KEY_2, '&','') as Project_Code,
    FIELD_NAME,
    AUDIT_OLD_VALUE,
    AUDIT_NEW_VALUE

FROM TBADT_AUDIT_TRAIL 

Case
    If
    Len (Project_Code) <= 4
    then 
    Left (Project_Code, 4) as Proj_Code
    else
    Right (Project_Code, 2) as Proj_Phase

    End If

where Key_1 like 'WKSCHART'
and
Audit_Date between '2017-06-13' and '2017-06-14'
```

Comment: What database platform?  Please tag.

Comment: why is there a case statement after FROM?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve 
Using IIF otherwise CASE, if the length of the new Key2 is over 4 then there is a project phase otherwise will only be a project code?

```
SELECT
  KEY_1,
  KEY_2,
  IIF(LEN(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', '')) <= 4, LEFT(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 4), '') Project_code,
  IIF(LEN(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', '')) > 4, RIGHT(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 2), '') Project_Phase,
  FIELD_NAME,
  AUDIT_OLD_VALUE,
  AUDIT_NEW_VALUE
FROM TBADT_AUDIT_TRAIL
WHERE Key_1 LIKE 'WKSCHART'
AND Audit_Date BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-14'
```

OR  Project Code is the Left 4 and Project Phase is the Right 2

```
SELECT
  KEY_1,
  KEY_2,
  LEFT(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 4) Project_code,
  RIGHT(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 2) Project_Phase,
  FIELD_NAME,
  AUDIT_OLD_VALUE,
  AUDIT_NEW_VALUE
FROM TBADT_AUDIT_TRAIL
WHERE Key_1 LIKE 'WKSCHART'
AND Audit_Date BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-14'
```

Comment: The first one is better but there is a problem with the brackets. I fixed it but it still doesnt work?

Comment: The error message: ERROR = Incorrect syntax near '>'

Comment: i'm not getting the error. question, is this on sql-server?

Comment: worked only when i use case statement, why is that?select 
    LEFT (REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 4) PROJECT_CODE,

    CASE    WHEN LEN(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''))  >4 THEN RIGHT(REPLACE(KEY_2, '&', ''), 2)    ELSE ''  END as PROJECT_PHASE,
        
    FIELD_NAME,
   AUDIT_OLD_VALUE,
   AUDIT_NEW_VALUE

 FROM TBADT_AUDIT_TRAIL 
 
where Key_1 like 'WKSCHART'
and
Audit_Date between '2017-06-13' and '2017-06-14'

Comment: that explains... IIF is not supported on your version thus use Case statement

Comment: Replace IIF with the case statement